# При вводе новой строковой переменной в запрос не возвращается значение

Tags: java, строки, get, retrofit

Проблема такая, если организовывать запрос с заранее готовыми параметрами, то все работает. Ответ возвращается. Как только ввожу переменную для передачи значения в запрос из текстового поля EditText по кнопке Button получаю проблему. Привожу для сравнения код (там, где закомментил в getArtistInfo запрос работает, а со строковой переменной - нет). Может неправильно ее (переменную "st") объявляю и передаю?

Сам код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;
    private String st;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);



    }

    private void getArtistInfo() {

        Retrofit retrofit = NetworkClient.getRetrofitClient();
        MusicInterface musicInterface = retrofit.create(MusicInterface.class);

        //Call callArtist = musicInterface.getArtistInfoMusic("artist.getinfo","Cher","6c8dc87e402c8f96b8369f927ca0c1be", "json");
        Call callArtist = musicInterface.getArtistInfoMusic("artist.getinfo", st, "6c8dc87e402c8f96b8369f927ca0c1be", "json");

            try {
                Response<ArtistInfo> responseArtistInfo = callArtist.execute();
                ArtistInfo artistInfo = responseArtistInfo.body();

                final Artist artist = artistInfo.getArtist();

                final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(artist.getName());

                textView.setText("Artist is - " + sb);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("caught IOException: " + e);
            }
        }



    public void StartBtn(View view) {

        StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
        st.append(R.id.editText);


        getArtistInfo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, неправильно. Вообще не передаёте. И учитесь читать текст ошибок, там все написано.

Answer (score 1):

Вы напутали во многих местах:

1. Вы не присваиваете переменной `st`, которая объявлена в классе, никакого значения, вместо этого, вы присваиваете локальной переменной в методе `StartBtn`.
2. Зачем вы присоединяете `id` поля `EditText` переменной? Текст от этого не появится.

   ```
   st = new StringBuilder();
   st.append(R.id.editText);
   ```

Чтобы всё заработало вам нужно прочитать значение поля и записать его в `st` переменную класса.

```
    public void StartBtn(View view) {
      st = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)).getText().toString();

      getArtistInfo();
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но, честно говоря, мысль была такая, что достаточно присоединить значение поля. Но тут сказывается недостаток знаний. Здорово, что помогли.